# Adjust size of SVG without affecting other elements

Tags: html, css, svg

I am new to SVG apologies! I am having an issue with an SVG where I have it set to `max-width: 60%` but it seems to take precedence over the overall height of the elements.

I want it so the overall height of the row is 50vh.  But even if I set it and remove the max-width from the SVG it still is taking precedence over the set vh.  If anyone has any suggestions on the best way to approach this?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="safetyFreelancer.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-vSIIfh2YWi9wW0r9iZe7RJPrKwp6bG+s9QZMoITbCckVJqGCCRhc+ccxNcdpHuYu" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        body {
            background: #f3f4f5;
        }
        .wave-container {
            position: relative;
            background: #ce1212;
            color: #FFF;
            text-align: center;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .wave-container > svg {
            display: block;
            background: #ce1212;
        }
        .vh {
            height: 50vh !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wave-container">
    <div class="row vh">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1 class="text-center">Welcome</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            SVG
        </div>
    </div>
    SVG
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I did not enter the SVGs as it maxes out the character count

Comment: maybe you could provide a live example with jsfiddle (or any other online editor).

Comment: @DavidB. Sorry https://jsfiddle.net/iamandyie/tmpcL78v/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I undestood correclty you want to set `width` for your svg. If yes, then you can just set through this new rule:

```
.col-md-6.test > svg {
    width: 50%;
}
```

[The jsfiddle example can be seen here.](https://jsfiddle.net/5gtje9mr/)